# Can I use Jquery to insert an asp.net control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use the following Jquery statement to place a asp.net control.

This works -

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $( "<p>test</p>" ).insertAfter( "#dropdownlogin" );

 });
```

but when I swap *test* with the *login control* it doesn't work.

```
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $( "<View:LoginNavigation ID="LoginNavigation1" runat="server"/>" ).insertAfter( "#dropdownlogin" );

     });
</script>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The control you're trying to insert needs to be compiled on the server. You can not insert it the way you're attempting.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to find a simpler solution rather than compile the control.

Comment: Why do you want to do this this way? Why can't you have the control already on the page?

Comment: I need to use the control in two separate headers, 1 for desktop and 1 for mobile. I was hoping to find a simple jquery solution to move the login control depending on the screen width.

Comment: Why don't you render them both though but change the visibility of the control via JQuery?

Comment: The page wont run due to login control ID being used twice

Comment: Sorry, I'm still lost... Does it matter if 1 is desktop and the other mobile? I mean, is it just the design/CSS that matters? Or do they offer different functionality?

Comment: So the login control is the same in header1 & header2 - the headers are alternated depending on the screen size. If I just place the login control in both headers the page wont run due to the controls ID being used twice, so im trying to find a way of placing the control once, and then alternating its position depending on the screen size

Comment: This sounds like your issue has nothing to do with the control, more due to styling in a "responsive design" fashion? Or do I miss the point :(

Comment: The issue is that the control cant be used twice on the same page so I need some way of moving it around. Thanks for your help though it is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see why you need 2 controls. It sounds like you have 2 controls to suit a design issue. If you can use a responsive design (CSS) you can place the single control where ever you like? There is no need to have 2 controls?

Comment: Yes that will work, but at the moment I have to separate headers which are shown or hidden depending on the screen width. Updating the CSS will take a few hours so I was hoping to find a simple method of moving the control with Jquery

Comment: You would need to use 2 id's then, but this would mean some (could be minimal) duplicated code...

Comment: That would be the simplest solution! unfortunately I don't work with c# - I looked into changing the ID earlier today and decided it was best left alone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The control you're trying to insert needs to be compiled on the server. You can't do what you want with your current approach.

Based upon your question and the comments, you are considering having 2 controls with the same ID and functionality. As you know, you can't have 2, your goal is add or remove one of the controls at run time.

However, the actual issue you have (and the reason you're trying to use 2 controls) is because you want them displayed on different positions of the website depending on the screen size.

I suggest you use the control only once, and use CSS (Media Query) to position it accordingly. May be looking at responsive design will help.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only works on client side (the users browser). Asp.Net controls are compiled on server side and generate normal html code (sometimes with javascript) that.